# search bmp file with specific name delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have bmp files in directory and subdirectory.
example: \fileserver\dir + subdir

the bmp file name is for example dddklk85243ggg.bmp

**Question:**

I need to serach the file by 85243 and when find first then put it to image on form.

I know to find file according a file name:

```
uses FindFile;
 ...
 procedure Tform1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject) ;
 var DFile : TFindFile;
 begin
   DFile := TFindFile.Create(nil) ;
   try
    DFile.FileAttr := [ffaAnyFile];
    DFile.InSubFolders := True;
    DFile.Path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) ;
    DFIle.FileMask := '*.bmp';

    Memo1.Lines := DFile.SearchForFiles;
   finally
    DFile.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

but how to check if file name containes some string?

Comment: You've stated a requirement rather than asked a question. What is your question please?

Comment: Hello, I don't know how to find file with name dddklk85243ggg.bmp by typying string 85243 somewhere ( edit, memo ).

Comment: What don't you know? How to enumerate files? Or how to search for text inside a string? Both topics that have been covered here repeatedly.

Comment: I would like to put text 85243 to memo.line and search files which file name containe this string, if yes load this bmp to image.

Comment: Generally it helps if you show what you've tried so far,and indicate where you got stuck, or what's not working as expected.

Comment: So what exactly don't you know how to do? On the face of it, it seems that you don't know how to do any of this. In which case what are we to do? Write your entire program? Please edit the question so that we can assess what you know, and what you don't, and how to steer you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some like this:

```
{: Search files in a directory; You can especify a mask for files.
   Optionaly you can especify recursively=True for subdirectories.
StartDir Folder ti serach.
FileMask Mask for files.
Recursively if you want searcjh on subdirectories.
FilesList  TStringList with names of files (path).
}
procedure FindFiles(StartDir, FileMask: string; 
                 recursively: boolean; var FilesList: TStringList);
const
  MASK_ALL_FILES = '*.*';
  CHAR_POINT = '.';
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  DirList: TStringList;
  IsFound: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin

  if (StartDir[length(StartDir)] <> '\') then begin
    StartDir := StartDir + '\';
  end;

  // Crear la lista de ficheros en el dir. StartDir (no directorios!)
  // Start with the search
  IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir + FileMask, 
                  faAnyFile - faDirectory, SR) = 0;

  // MIentras encuentre
  // while found files...
  while IsFound do begin
    FilesList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;

  FindClose(SR);

  // Recursivo? 
  if (recursively) then begin
    // Build a list of subdirectories
    DirList := TStringList.Create;
    // proteccion
    try
      IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir + MASK_ALL_FILES, 
                   faAnyFile, SR) = 0;
      while IsFound do begin
        if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and 
          (SR.Name[1] <>  CHAR_POINT) then begin
          DirList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
          IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
        end; // if
      end; // while
    FindClose(SR);
    // Scan the list of subdirectories
    for i := 0 to DirList.Count - 1 do begin
      FindFiles(DirList[i], FileMask, recursively, FilesList);
    end;

    finally
      DirList.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can call the procedure with:

```
var
  filesList:TStringList;
begin
  ...
  FindFiles('\fileserver\dir\' + subdir, '*85243*.bmp', True, filesList);
...
```

Regards.